# Godot Input Bug, or am I missing something?

Tags: input, godot, spotbugs

I’m making a top-down rpg game, and I want to use the arrow keys to move the player. I keep running into a problem where if all 4 keys are held down at once and then released at roughly the same time, the player starts moving in a direction, usually the right.

First I thought my code was the problem, but as far as I can tell there are no problems with it. Then I decided to stick `print(Input.is_action_pressed(“move right”))` in my physics process, and I found something interesting: After pressing and releasing all 4 keys at the same time, `True` was printed in the Output window and my player continued moving to the right.

This suggests that the problem is with Godot thinking I’m pressing keys that aren’t pressed, not my code having logic errors. Also this doesn’t seem to happen when I change my Inputs to WASD; only the arrow keys.

Does anyone know if this is a bug? Can anyone recreate this by setting up inputs for right, left, up, and down, and printing `is_action_pressed` for them? Or is the issue probably something that’s my fault?

Comment: Have you tried reproducing this behavior in a separate project or application, or with a different keyboard?

Comment: I have tried several projects, but I haven’t tried other keyboards/devices. I’ll try that now.

Comment: I tried an online keyboard test instead, and it also thinks I’m pressing the right arrow key when I’m not. The problem isn’t with Godot, it’s my keyboard. At least it wasn’t my code though lol. Thank you.